# Authenticating with Azure AD using UPN (User principal name)

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have Angular 9 client calling Azure Functions. I started off with `msal-angular` package using "implicit grant flow" for authentication, and that worked fine.

My client app registration in Azure has its Authentication set to `"Accounts in this organizational directory only (Default Directory only - Single tenant)"`. I can't change this setting as the app will only be available to company users.

I'm using my personal Microsoft account with Gmail username (e.g.: `user@gmail.com`). This account is a "Guest" in Azure AD, so far, so good.

I'm moving away from `msal-angular` and implementing `PKCE authentication flow`.

I'm using `angular-auth-oidc-client` package. My `stsServer` and `authWellknownEndpoint` are set to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant-id]/v2.0` (turned out to be the problem, see update at the bottom)

Here are the login scenarios I'm having issues with:

1. When I use my `user@gmail.com`, I get `"unauthotized_client ..."` error right after I enter my username
   [image]
2. When I use my UPN (e.g.: `user@gmail.com#EXT#@our_ad_owner.onmicrosoft.com`) I get to the password prompt, but my Microsoft password doesn't work. I understand why it doesn't work (that password has nothing to do with AD), but I can't figure out how to set AD password for that account.

**When I try to reset my password in AD, it tells me that `"user@gmail.com is a Microsoft account that is managed by the user. Only user@gmail.com can reset their password for this account."`**

---

**Any help with setting AD password for my UPN would be appreciated. I would also like to know if it's possible to login with my actual email address, and not UPN.**

---

**UPDATE: The problem was with `angular-auth-oidc-client` setup, `authWellknownEndpoint` was set to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0`, after I changed it to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant-id]/v2.0` it worked!**

Comment: Is your authority configured to be your tenant in the front-end?

Comment: If everything works correctly, you should get redirected to personal MS account login page from AAD login page..

Comment: @juunas client configuration is fine, it worked with "implicit grant flow", I'm reusing same client, just disabled "Access tokens" and "ID tokens" to enable PKCE

Comment: @juunas authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant-id]/v2.0

Comment: And you changed the platform to SPA in app registration?

Comment: @juunas it was a SPA all along, I've added more info on my new setup to the question. I've also created another client registration allowing "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)" auth, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share the address url (is it begin with `https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?`?) when you get the first error? I can repro your first error when I use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0`. But you mentioned your authority is  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant-id]/v2.0`. So I need more information.

Comment: @AllenWu `https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=[client-id]&scope=openid+profile+email+[azure-function]%2fuser_impersonation&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a4200&response_type=code&state=[guid]&nonce=[guid]&code_challenge=d4E6xxxxx&code_challenge_method=S256&uaid=[guid]&msproxy=1&issuer=mso&tenant=common&ui_locales=en-US`

Comment: If so, the endpoint on your side should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0`. When the login window pops up, you should be able to see it in the address bar. See `tenant=common` in the url you shared above.

Comment: @AllenWu restore your post, I'll accept it as answer. it prompted me to double check my configuation, and my `authWellknownEndpoint` was set to  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0`. After I changed it to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant-id]/v2.0` it worked!

Comment: @romanm Sure! Glad to know this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the first error because you are using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0` as the authority. It treats your account as personal account rather than the guest account in your tenant. But your Azure AD app is configured as `Accounts in this organizational directory only (Default Directory only - Single tenant)`, which is not supported for consumers (personal account). See the reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#fetch-the-openid-connect-metadata-document).

So you should use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your tenant id}/v2.0` as the authority. Then it will allow your `user@gmail.com` to sign in.